# Key missing in TreeSet

Tags: java, treeset

I'm adding the hashMap key to one by one in treeSet and try to sort them based on comparator passed in lambda in treeSet.

Without comparator, it is working fine based on default TreeSet.

```java
String s = "tree";
        Map<Character, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
        for(char ch:s.toCharArray()){
            freqMap.put(ch,freqMap.getOrDefault(ch,0)+1);
        }
        // need to sort TreeSet key with frequency wise
        TreeSet<Character> sortByFreq = new TreeSet<Character>((a,b)->freqMap.get(b).intValue() - freqMap.get(a).intValue());
        for(char ch :freqMap.keySet()){
            System.out.println("from HashMap "+ch);
            sortByFreq.add(ch);
            System.out.println("after adding "+ch+" Treeset like "+sortByFreq);

        }
        System.out.println(freqMap.keySet());
        System.out.println(sortByFreq);
```

Missing some key in treeSet. What am I doing wrong in treeSet?

O/P

> ```
> from HashMap r
> after adding r Treeset like [r]
> from HashMap t
> after adding t Treeset like [r]
> from HashMap e
> after adding e Treeset like [e, r]
> [r, t, e]
> [e, r]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Your sorting criteria for the `TreeSet` also defines which elements are considered equal to each other. This means two keys with the same frequency in `freqMap` will be deemed equal, so only one of them will be added to the `Set`.

If you want to have all the keys in the `TreeSet`, you should add to your `Comparator` a tie-breaker logic, to define the order of two characters having the same frequency.

```
TreeSet<Character> sortByFreq = new TreeSet<Character>((a,b)->{
                                                          int diff = Integer.compare(freqMap.get(b),freqMap.get(a)); 
                                                           return diff == 0 ? Character.compare(b,a) : diff;
                                                      });
```

Now the output will be:

```
[e, t, r]
```

EDIT:

Or, as Andreas suggested:

```
TreeSet<Character> sortByFreq = new TreeSet<Character>(Comparator.comparing((Character c) -> freqMap.get(c))
                                                                 .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())
                                                                 .reversed());
```

Comment: You can also write it as `new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing((Character c) -> freqMap.get(c)).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()).reversed())`

Comment: @Andreas thanks, I was trying to find a `thenComparing` version for this that passes compilation. Your version works.